# Using variables to obtain TOKEN via Azure CLI

Tags: bash, azure, curl

I am currently trying to get a Token for Authenticating towards Azure API via Github workflow bash step.
The values of the two variables are coming from Azure Keyvault and thats why i need to pass them in form of variables.

The command that i am using is the following:

```
- run: |

TOKEN=$(curl -X POST \
            -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${user}&client_secret=${password}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F' \
            https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant_id}/oauth2/token | jq -r '.access_token')
```

The value of TOKEN is always null.

If i try the same command, but use the values instead of variables ${user} and ${password} the token is created.

```
TOKEN=$(curl -X POST \
            -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=**MYUSER**&client_secret=**MYPASSWORD**&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F' \
            https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant_id}/oauth2/token | jq -r '.access_token')
```

Interesting is that only the 2 variables ${user} and ${password} are not being picked up, the variable for {tenant_id} works.

Why i cannot use the variables inside of grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=**${user}**&client_secret=**${password}**&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F'

This works in Azure Devops Pipeline , but not in Github Workflows

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes, else var substitution doesnt happen `"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${user}&client_secret=${password}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F"`

Comment: glad it worked. I posted as an answer, feel free to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes, else var substitution doesnt happen `"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${user}&client_secret=${password}&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F"`